# Pushing into different nexus repository always lands into one repo

Tags: docker, repository, private

I am trying to push an image into nexsus repo (myrepo):

```
docker push myreposerver/myrepo/httpd:2.4.28-alpine
```

And I see that it lands in another repo as:

```
myreposerver/otherrepo/myrepo/httpd:2.4.28-alpine
```

This is wrong, but I can't find where are config settings which are responsible for this behavior in Nexus UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Private+Registry+for+Docker

> The docker client does not allow a context as part of the path to a
>   registry, as the namespace and image name are embedded in the URLs it
>   uses. This is why requests to repositories on the repository manager
>   are served on a specific and separate port from the rest of the
>   application instead of how most other repositories serve content via a
>   path i.e. //

So, in a nutshell if one wants to setup separate Docker repositories in Nexus they have to be on separate ports, exactly as described here: http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2017/02/16/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-3-docker-images/